# Windows network share doesn't work as intended

Tags: windows, networking, windows-11, network-shares, windows-networking

On my main PC, when I try to connect to my other pc (I'll refer to it as "SERVER") through the network tab in file explorer I get the error "Windows cannot access \SERVER" with the description of "You do not have permission to access \SERVER".

I know network sharing is working though because if I got to \SERVER\Users I can access my files, it's just going to the root directory of the file share or the uppermost folder that it says I do not have permission. Is there some way I can fix this; it would be nice to just to go to \SERVER instead of \SERVER\Users all the time.

Comment: You have to share normal folders.  If you try to share secured folders, you would have add specific permission to these folder as an Admin

Comment: Even if I go ahead and just share a normal folder, going to \\SEREVER renders the same error. FYI the folder in currently sharing is just my user file

Comment: Make sure on the target computer that the USERS folder is properly shared. This is a secured folder. I share these folders only with my own computers

Comment: I do believe that it is properly shared

Comment: Use NET USE to map and see what numerical error you get

Comment: [Error 67](https://imgur.com/a/HW0BX0A)

Comment: Error 67 is a syntax error or possibly network driver error.  Try reinstalling the NIC adapter

Comment: Just did that with no success.

Comment: I am not sure then, what the issue is.